# How to do exact match on CloudSearch text field type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, text, literals, amazon-cloudsearch

We have a dynamic text field part_*, we store documents with fields part_brand, part_number and part_id. We want to retrieve all the part_ids for part_brand "abc" and part_number "123". When we search with below query

> (and part_brand:'abc' part_number:'123')

We get results for documents containing part_number 123-1, 123-2, "123 1" and so on.

Is there a way to retrieve part_ids for those documents which have an exact match for part_number "123"?

I know we can configure our field as literal so that we can get an exact match. But literals match is case-sensitive. We also want the search to be case-insensitive that is why we are using the text field.

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out?

Comment: @emilyk Yes i did. I figured out that it is not possible to exact match on "text" type. Ended up a logic in client code to filter out the non-exact match.